# Conflict Bootstrap, Prototype Js and Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, prototypejs, scriptaculous

After 7 days of search and after i have tried different solutions and it did not work i would like to ask:
I have a page with prototype js, protaplasm, and scriptaculous and jquery and Jquery-ui and it was working perfectly with the jquery no conflict until i recently downloaded  a design with Bootstrap and here comes the trouble. Prototype js fonctionalities are no more working. The ajax update of prototype js and the inplaceeditor the scriptaculous are no more working.
I have tried most work around but i did not really get the result. Does someone have a working solution ?

Comment: http://www.softec.lu/site/DevelopersCorner/BootstrapPrototypeConflict

Comment: I have tried this early on but It did not work. JQuery and bootstrap worked but not prototype js and scriptaculous

Comment: are any JS errors thrown when attempting to use the components?

Comment: the js error

uncaught exception: controls.js requires including script.aculo.us' effects.js library
 ReferenceError: Effect is not defined dragdrop.js:8
 TypeError: this.element.getStyle is not a function controls.js:498
 TypeError: this.element.getStyle is not a function controls.js:498
 TypeError: this.element.getStyle is not a function controls.js:498
 TypeError: this.element.getStyle is not a function controls.js:498
 TypeError: this.element.getStyle is not a function controls.js:498
 TypeError: element.dispatchEvent is not a function prototype.js:7066

But i do have effect.js

Comment: Maybe i am missing something here. How to introduce the prototype js with require.js . It seems in the exampld you gavs me prototype.js is not include

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer. To avoid conflict between Jquery, Prototype js, protoplasm, twitter bootstrap
First i added the jquery noconlict after jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $.noConflict();

    </script>
```

and i put every jquery code between

```
 jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
// Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

});
```

And most importantly i opened every other js file that uses jquery like bootstrap.min.js and i copied and pasted the code inside between

```
 jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.


    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    });
```

I still have an error like TypeError: this.element is null controls.js with Firebug but everything works perfectly